# Vue change array/object position or hierarchy

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, axios

Right now vue inside `mounted` function calls a napi and gets the value for `teambytime2`. When it fetch the values using an api it looks like

[image]

Below is the axios get url used to fetch the data and pass it on to `this.teamByTime2`.

```
axios.get(https://usemyapi90.com/currentDate).then(response => 
      (
        this.teamByTime2 = response.data
      ));
```

Structure for the fetched data is below

```
> teamByTime2
  >> 0
    >>> Booker
    >>> Player
    id
    updatedAt
    enter code here

  >> 1
    >>> Booker
    >>> Player
    id
    updatedAt
```

**Any suggestion on how to move object structure for `Booker` inside the `Player` ?**

```
> teamByTime2
  >> 0
    >>> Player
     >>>> Booker
    id
    updatedAt
    enter code here

  >> 1
    >>> Player
      >>>> Booker
    id
    updatedAt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the api code you can directly modify the data output, if you don't have access then you could do something like this:

```html
for(let i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){
   let item = data[i]
   item.Booker.Player = item.Player
  
  //if you wanna delete from main object 
   delete item.Player
  
  //push in the array
   this.teamByTime2.push(item)
}
```